# MySQL Error Code: 1526 Table has no partition for value 44285

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table which I have added list partitions

```
alter table *table1* partition by list (Key1)
(PARTITION pss_1 VALUES in (44285),
PARTITION pss_2 VALUES in (44291),
PARTITION pss_3 VALUES in (44321),
PARTITION pss_4 VALUES in (44348),
PARTITION pss_5 VALUES in (44350),
PARTITION pss_6 VALUES in (44351),
PARTITION pss_7 VALUES in (44352));
```

When I:

```
select distinct Key from *table1*;
```

I get:

```
44285,
44291,
44321,
44348,
44350
```

So why when I run the following:

```
alter table *table1* partition by list (Key)
(PARTITION pss_8 VALUES in (44353));
```

I get the error:

```
MySQL Error Code: 1526 Table has no partition for value 44285
```

Comment: What does your table definition look like? Do you have a `Key` value of 44353?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into this.  At the moment I do not have a Key of 44353, this was to be inserted later.   I now realise that I should have used an alter table add partition syntax: alter table table1 add partition (partition pss8 VALUES in (44353))

Answer (score 0):

Your `ALTER` is saying that there will be only one partition; it throws away the other 6.

Why are you using `PARTITION BY LIST`?  I know of no use for it.  If you think there is a performance case, let's see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` so I can dispute it.